# Python 3 TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting , lists issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program made in python 3.72 is supposed to recieve a number list from the user and then print four different lists with the numbers that are multiples of 2, 3, 5 and 7.

```
num_input = ""
num_list = []
while num_input != "ESC":
    if num_input.isdigit():
        print("Number added")
        num_list.append(num_input)
    num_input = input("Enter a number list [Type ESC to end list]: ")

num_list_2 = []
num_list_3 = []
num_list_5 = []
num_list_7 = []

for item in num_list:
    if item % 2 == 0:
        num_list_2.append(item)
    if item % 3 == 0:
        num_list_3.append(item)
    if item % 5 == 0:
        num_list_5.append(item)
    if item % 7 == 0:
        num_list_7.append(item)

print(num_list_2)
print(num_list_3)
print(num_list_5)
print(num_list_7)
```

when I ran the code it did well until I wrote "ESC" to end the list and it showed this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in 
<module>
    if item % 2 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Your list consists of strings, not of numbers. Fix append() call as follows: num_list.append(int(num_input))

Comment: `%` is a formatting operator with a string on the left side.  Convert to integer as suggested by other comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` function in python returns a string. If you need integers (here you do for calculing the mod), you'll need to cast the return value of `input` to int with `int(input("..."))`

Answer (score 0):

`%` is actually a string formatting operator, since `item` is actually a string, so use:

```
num_input = ""

num_list = []
while num_input != "ESC":
    if num_input.isdigit():
        print("Number added")
        num_list.append(int(num_input))
    num_input = input("Enter a number list [Type ESC to end list]: ")

num_list_2 = []
num_list_3 = []
num_list_5 = []
num_list_7 = []

for item in num_list:
    if item % 2 == 0:
        num_list_2.append(item)
    if item % 3 == 0:
        num_list_3.append(item)
    if item % 5 == 0:
        num_list_5.append(item)
    if item % 7 == 0:
        num_list_7.append(item)

print(num_list_2)
print(num_list_3)
print(num_list_5)
print(num_list_7)
```